# Android Vertical Tab Item

Tags: android, themes, vertical-alignment, tabitem

I have an android app in which I have a multiple "Categories" each with some items associated with it. Like an online electronics shop for instance where you would have categories such as Computers, Printers, cameras etc. as categories and then each of those would have some items in them.

These categories should be displayed as "tabs" just like this image, can you help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiV0L.png)

Comment: Help you to what? What is your problem? You could do that with a vertical LinearLayout

Comment: Look at the image I had sent , all I want is one way for using Tabitem vertically , not horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Use fragments.

1. Divide your screen in two by two **FrameLayout**
2. Create a fragment with as much **TextViews** as much tabs you have.
       Then open a fragment you need after pressing TextView.

Try to do that, then you can make your tabs with ListView and populate them dymamically and independantly of tabs count.

Comment: I used navigation drawer, but still can't prepare Vertical tabitem

Comment: Do you want you tabs always visible?

Comment: yeah , are you using Instagram ? in instagram we have many tab item on top of the app, all I want is a way for showing tab on side of the app(left or right of the app), just like the image I had set : http://i.stack.imgur.com/eiV0L.png